# Adding elements in Magnific Popup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lightbox, magnific-popup

I've added Magnific Popup gem in my Rails web app, and have initialized it simply with

```
$('.box p a').magnificPopup({
    type:'image'
});
```

in my application.js.

How do I go about modifying content of the popup window? I would like to add some hover effects on left and right side of the image displayed in popup, in such way that if I, for example, hover on the right side of the image - div container with certain image info slides in.

Thank you for any information!

Answer (score 1):

`image.markup` option allows you to change the HTML structure of popup content - http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#image_type

Also, you may just use "inline" type of popup, and provide all the content by yourself.